# How to solve Matlab recursion RecursionDetected error in hgload?

Tags: user-interface, exception, matlab, recursion

My matlab gui uses a button click to launch another gui.

Recently I've found that if click intesively on that button, I cause matlab to crash with recursion error (see description below).
What caused this recursion error, and how do I solve it for next time?

**Error description:**

??? Error using ==> hgload>localCheckRecursion at 155
Recursion occurs when loading c:\Algo\MyGUI.fig.

Error in ==> hgload at 56
Guard = localCheckRecursion(fullpath);  %#ok

Error in ==> openfig at 72
    [fig, savedvisible] = hgload(filename, struct('Visible','off'));

Error in ==> gui_mainfcn>local_openfig at 286
    gui_hFigure = openfig(name, singleton, visible);

Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 159
        gui_hFigure = local_openfig(gui_State.gui_Name, gui_SingletonOpt,
        gui_Visible);

Error in ==> PumpControl at 42
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking repeatedly on a GUI button can cause multiple invocations of the button callback, which may interrupt one another at certain points and cause unwanted messes. This is probably the problem you are having.

You can design GUI controls in MATLAB such that they ignore rapid clicking like this by setting the [`'BusyAction'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol_props.html#bqxoija) and [`'Interruptible'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uicontrol_props.html#bqxohrx) properties as follows (where `hButton` is a [handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f3-15974.html) to your button object):

```
set(hButton,'BusyAction','cancel','Interruptible','off');
```

Setting `'Interruptible'` to `'off'` means that the button callback can't be interrupted when it is running (except by certain "special" callbacks), and setting `'BusyAction'` to `'cancel'` means that a button click will be ignored when another callback (or its own) is already executing.

Answer (score 0):

That usually means that your callback is doing something which lets more events come in, which starts another copy of your callback, etc...

The usual fix is to not do the thing which is letting events get processed. The classic is to use drawnow('expose') instead of drawnow because drawnow('expose') will let paint events get processed without letting more button clicks through.

It sounds like the problem in your case is that the hgload is letting events through. There are a few commands (e.g. figure) which do this, and it can be difficult to find a workaround for these. You can up your recursion limit, but that's only going to postpone the problem.

Sorry I don't have a solution for you.